# Class 'Logger' not found in LoggerRoot.php

Tags: php, log4php

I'm trying to install log4php in a very simple site (trying to learn how it works).
Apache is installed in /etc/ and vhost is defined as:

DocumentRoot "/home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/www"
    ServerName tutorial.localhost
    php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/www/ConfigureSite.php"
  
My site is at /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/www/ and log4php folder is at /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/

Then, I define

```
define('LOG4PHP_DIR', "/home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/");
```

into ConfigureSite.php

And, into another file, I try to init log4php:

```
include(LOG4PHP_DIR."/Logger.php");
$log = Logger::getLogger("main");
$log->info("foo");
$log->warn("bar");
```

The error is always the same:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Logger' not found in /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/LoggerRoot.php on line 37
```

It's worth to say that LoggerRoot.php and Logger.php are in the same folder. I think I have a problem of paths because my server and my site aren't in the same folder, but I need some hint

Adding the complete stack trace of error:

```
    [22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Logger' not found in /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/LoggerRoot.php on line 36
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP Stack trace:
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   1. {main}() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/www/index.php:0
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   2. require_once() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/www/index.php:12
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   3. require_once() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/www/greet_at_opening.php:11
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   4. require_once() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/Logger.php:24
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   5. require_once() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/LoggerCategory.php:27
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   6. require_once() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/spi/LoggerLoggingEvent.php:28
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   7. require_once() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/LoggerManager.php:29
[22-May-2012 11:34:38] PHP   8. require_once() /home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/services/lib/log4php-0.9/src/log4php/LoggerHierarchy.php:28
```

So, first, Logger is found but on loading LoggerHierarchy, Logger isn't. Why????

SOLVED: The error is to use log4php-0.9 and php5 together. Downloading the library located in apache web (2.1), the problem is solved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is to use log4php-0.9 and php5 together. Downloading the library located in apache web (2.1), the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think using  `dirname(__FILE__)` will look better.

I also thought it would be the path...

Maybe the Class name defenition then. do you call `new Logger` in Logger.php?

What about something like:

```
include(LOG4PHP_DIR."/Logger.php");
$log = new Logger();
$log->info("foo");
```

Comment: "/home/fferri/workspace/site-tutorial/www/log4php//Logger.php" is perfectly legal in unix

Comment: Hmmm... I see, Then maybe you need to create new Logger object first? - edited awnser