# Class 'Logger' not found in LoggerRoot.php when using require_once

Tags: php, log4php

I am using log4php here, and keeping get error when using require_once:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../log4php';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
require_once 'Logger.php';

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Logger' not found in /home/user/project/log4php/LoggerRoot.php on line 37.
```

Already tried to add the log4php folder to the include_path, and using the full path of log4php, but no luck. Actually, I use eclipse, and in eclipse, I can Ctrl+click to Logger class, which means the path should have no problem.

Any idea?

Thanks very much~

---

Solution:
Still have no idea about the error I had, but it seems because I used the old pure log4php lib from this [link](http://www.vxr.it/log4php/download.html) . After changing to use the new lib of [2.3.0](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/download.html), then the problem solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class 'Logger' not found in LoggerRoot.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689340/class-logger-not-found-in-loggerroot-php)

Comment: @Stony, thanks, as my project is not an apache project, it dose not work for me.